# What is the best way to solve for A when det(sI-A) is required to have desired characteristics?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I want to solve unknown matrix A, where $A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{array}\right]$ s.t  $\text{det}\left(sI-A\right)$ has  the characteristic equation $s^3+\lambda_1s^2+\lambda_2s+\lambda_3$.
What will be easiest way to solve for the matrix A?

Comment: You can't solve $A$ since you only have 3 inputs $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ for essentially 9 unknowns $a_{ij}$. If you just want a matrix with given characteristic polynomial, try the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually infinitely many $A$ with a given characteristic polynomial.  One easy way of finding some examples is by taking $A$ to be a [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) or a conjugate of such a matrix.